# Why do the names of overriding arguments have to match those of the abstract interface?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran2003

Why do the names of arguments in overriding procedures need to match those of the abstract interface?

I understand that clearly the `TYPE`, `INTENT`, etc of such arguments are required to match the interface, but why should the compiler care what I call my variables?

In the following, I've defined a simple abstract utility class containing a single deferred procedure `EVAL` that takes a double precision argument.

```
!------------------------------------- an abstract utility class !
type, abstract :: func_1d
contains
    procedure(interface_1d),deferred :: eval
end type func_1d

!-------------------------------------------- interface for eval !
abstract interface
function interface_1d(this,data) result(rval)
    import :: func_1d
    class(func_1d), intent(inout) :: this
    real*8        , intent(in)    :: data
    real*8 :: rval
end function interface_1d
end interface
```

Defining an overriding class and an implementation for `EVAL`:

```
type, extends(func_1d) :: foo
contains
    procedure, pass :: eval => eval_foo
end type foo

function eval_foo(this,another_variable_name) result(rval)
    implicit none
    class(foo), intent(inout) :: this
    real*8, intent(in) :: another_variable_name
    real*8 :: rval

    !! etc

end function eval_foo
```

I get the following error from `gfortran`:

> Error: Dummy argument 'another_variable_name' of 'eval' at (1) should be named 'data'
>   as to match the corresponding argument of the overridden procedure

If I instead substitute `DATA` for `ANOTHER_VARIABLE_NAME` everything compiles and runs as expected.

But this seems silly to me. I want to be able to inherit from `FUNC_1D` multiple times, and under various circumstances and being forced to call my variables `DATA` every time seems ridiculous.

I don't understand why the compiler should be interested in more than the `TYPE` and `INTENT` of the arguments?

Comment: I don't know but I suspect that it may be down to Fortran's argument keyword capabilities, which mean that you can call your function like this `fun_1d(data=the_data,this=that)`, that is you can name the arguments in the call rather than rely on position matching.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: I see. I didn't know you could do that, and it seems like it probably explains the behaviour...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elaborating on High Performance Mark's comment

> I don't know but I suspect that it may be down to Fortran's argument keyword capabilities, which mean that you can call your function like this `fun_1d(data=the_data,this=that)`, that is you can name the arguments in the call rather than rely on position matching.

consider the following

```
type, extends(func_1d) :: foo
 contains
  procedure, pass :: eval => eval_foo
end type foo

type, extends(func_1d) :: bar
 contains
  procedure, pass :: eval => eval_bar
end type bar
```

with appropriate procedure definitions with interfaces

```
real*8 function eval_foo(this,foo_var)
  class(foo), intent(inout) :: this
  real*8, intent(in) :: foo_var
end function

real*8 function eval_bar(this,bar_var)
  class(bar), intent(inout) :: this
  real*8, intent(in) :: bar_var
end function
```

then later

```
class(func_1d), allocatable :: baz
allocate (foo_or_bar :: baz)  ! For one of the types foo, bar
```

which, if any, makes sense with an argument keyword?

```
print*, baz%eval(data=s)
print*, baz%eval(foo_var=s)
print*, baz%eval(bar_var=s)
```

[There are cases where this would be much more pronounced, especially with optional dummy arguments.]

---

The standard requires that you keep the same dummy argument names (very likely to avoid the issue above).  See 12.4.1 ISO/IEC 1539-1:2010:

> **12.4.1 Interface and abstract interface**
>
> The interface of a procedure determines the forms of reference through which it may be invoked. The procedure’s
>   interface consists of its name, binding label, generic identifiers, characteristics, and the names of its dummy
>   arguments. The characteristics and binding label of a procedure are fixed, but the remainder of the interface may
>   differ in differing contexts, except that for a separate module procedure body (12.6.2.5), the dummy argument
>   names and whether it is recursive shall be the same as in its corresponding separate interface body (12.4.3.2).

This states that separate procedures using the same interface shall have the same dummy argument names as the interface.  This is further strengthened by 4.5.7.3:

> The overriding and overridden type-bound procedures shall satisfy the following conditions.
>   - [...]
>   - Dummy arguments that correspond by position shall have the same names and characteristics, except for the type of the passed-object dummy arguments.

Comment: `real*8` is not valid Fortran and was never part of the ISO Fortran standard.

Comment: Feel free to edit that out of the answer.  It's there only because of its feature in the question.