# Overriding the parent procedure with the same name

Tags: oop, fortran

I am trying to understand how inheritance works in Fortran but having difficulty with the following code (sorry if this is a FAQ...):

```
module mymod
    implicit none

    type Pos
        integer :: n_ = -1
    contains
        procedure :: set => Pos_set
    endtype

    type, extends(Pos) :: Vec
        integer :: x_ = -2
    contains
        procedure :: set => Vec_set         !! (1)
        !! procedure :: set => Vec_set_p    !! (2)
    endtype

contains

    subroutine Pos_set( p, n )
        class(Pos) p
        integer n
        p% n_ = n
    endsubroutine

    subroutine Vec_set( v, n )
        class(Vec) v
        integer n
        v% n_ = n
        v% x_ = n * 10
    endsubroutine

    subroutine Vec_set_p( p, n )
         class(Vec) p
         integer n
         p% n_ = n
         p% x_ = n * 10
    endsubroutine

end

program main
    use mymod
    implicit none
    type(Pos) p
    type(Vec) v

    call p% set( 10 )
    call v% set( 20 )

    print *, "p = ", p
    print *, "v = ", v
end
```

With the above code, gfortran 5.2.1 gives the following error message:

```
procedure :: set => Vec_set
        1
Error: Dummy argument ‘v’ of ‘set’ at (1) should be named ‘p’
as to match the corresponding argument of the overridden procedure
```

If I change the binding of `set` to `Vec_set_p` (i.e. replace Line 1 by 2), which is different from `Vec_set` only by the name of the first dummy argument, then the program compiles fine and gives the expected result. I got a similar error from ifort-14.0 and Oracle Fortran also.

Does this mean that, to override the procedure of the parent type, we need to take care of the name of dummy arguments also? (i.e., not only the information on which class is used but also the name of variable?)

Comment: Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29011920)?

Comment: Does this mean that, because Fortran allows a type constructor to be used with keyword arguments (with an arbitrary order), we need to retain the same names with those used in the most parent one? Because this is probably not so common in other languages (I think they are usually regarded as positional arguments), I feel it is very confusing (if that is the case...)

Comment: And yeah, excpet for the use of abstract thing, my question seems like a duplicate of the linked one. Thanks very much for pointing to the page :)

Comment: I don't think I'd call it an exact duplicate, but 4.5.7.3 does explicitly mention the case of the name of the passed-object dummy argument being identical.  The motivation is possibly slightly different, but I can't really explain just at the moment.

Comment: Sorry for my comment above, which is I feel chaotic (the problem is about a type-bound procedure, not a type constructor...)

Comment: You may use the `non_overridable` binding-attribute to prevent children, i.e., type extensions, from overriding a particular type-bound procedure from their parents. By default any type-bound procedure may be overwritten as long as you preserve the interface (signature). Recall that, unlike Java, Fortran is call by keyword just like Python.

Comment: @roygvib FYI, I always use `this` as the polymorphic pass dummy argument in my codes. You'll never have to worry about matching the correct names. This is why the Python community chose `self`; I've encountered may Pythonistas who didn't know that `self` is not a reserved keyword in Python it’s just a strong convention.

Comment: @jlokimlin Using `this` or some such unique identifier makes sense in many cases, but it is possible to bind the same procedure to many types (so different passed objects) and only one dummy argument may be called that.  [One could argue about whether this multiple binding is good style...]

Comment: @jlokimlin Thanks, yeah, I also usually use a fixed name for the first argument (in my case, I like the name `me` rather than `this` or `self` to save two characters). But this name constraint also applies to all the other arguments, so a bit surprise to me... (though it could be thought of natural if it is to provide the same "method").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an answer with good motivation to it, but: yes, you need to care about the names of the dummy arguments.

That particular restriction comes (in Fortran 2008) in 4.5.7.3.  As you have pointed out, what you have here is overriding of the binding name `set` from the type `pos` in the type `vec`.  Overriding occurs when a type-bound procedure in an extending type has the same binding name as an accessible type-bound procedure in the parent type.

For overriding to be allowed there are many conditions given in that noted section.  Of note are the following two:

- Passed-object dummy arguments, if any, shall correspond by name and position.
- Dummy arguments that correspond by position shall have the same names and characteristics, except for the type of the passed-object dummy arguments.

Without the `pass` attribute on the type-bound procedure the passed-object dummy argument is the first argument in the argument list.  As your compiler complains, the overriding procedure has passed-object name different.

The question's example doesn't use polymorphism, so to some extent one here needn't care about overriding (the procedures could have different binding names).

For polymorphic work where this dynamic resolution is wanted, ensure the above restrictions are met.  As commented by jlokimlin using a fairly generic name for the passed dummy argument, like `this` or `self` which are popular, is an easy way to deal with this problem in all but strange cases.

Alternatively, a crucial part about overriding is that the parent's type-bound procedure be accessible.  If the two derived types are declared in different modules and the parent's type-bound procedure is private then no overriding happens and the restrictions don't apply.  [Of course, then the parent's binding name can be used only in its defining module, but that may be sufficient in many cases.]

Comment: Thanks very much for your explanations. I've been reading related sections in the standards, but one questions: In this [page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29011920/why-do-the-names-of-overriding-arguments-have-to-match-those-of-the-abstract-int) you explained an example of `print*, baz%(data=s)` etc, but I have never seen this syntax before. So could you explain what this syntax means? Is it a short-hand notation to call a type-bound procedure? (some keyword is OK, then I will search the info).

Comment: That's just standard _keyword_  (you did say some "keyword is enough"...) argument passing, much as if it were any other function.  You'll most likely come across this in examples where optional arguments at the end of a list are present with some before missing, but more widely arguments can be passed in any order in the argument list and associated with the actual argument merely by keyword.  (As you're looking at the standard document, see 12.5, etc.)

Comment: Ah, I see... In Fortran, we can use keyword-based argument association (in any order) even for positional arguments. (Is this correct? I've read this before somewhere, but never used in my programs so not very sure.) And does `baz%(data=s)` in your explanation mean `baz% eval( data=s )` if written more explicitly? (I initially thought of this as some special syntax of a constructor or something, because routine name is omitted...)

Comment: Actually, what you've found there is just a massive typo...  Corrected.  Sorry for the confusion, and how my comment earlier just completely missed it.

Comment: I see, OK no problem :) As for the keyword-based argument association, I still think that it would probably be possible for a compiler to handle this solely by the position of the arguments (by some internal mapping or something), but the standards might want to keep things not too complicated... Just a guess :) (I guess things would have been simpler if there is no keyword association for positional arguments.)

Comment: Your question inspired me to write [some documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/47068).